# How can i play an animation after pressing space?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've got a list of images to animate a basic attack, but i don't know how to play through them when space is pressed.

For the walk animation it was easy because i just played

```
    walkcount = 0
    walkanim = [list of images]

    if direction:
        win.blit(walkanim[walkCount // n], (x, y))
        if walkCount + 1 >= 18:
            walkCount = 0
        else:
            walkCount += 1
```

But I don't understand how to play through a whole list of images in a timely manner if space is pressed.

because once its pressed then its false again

Answer (score 0):

The two ways you might want to do this are either: Interrupt the process of the run cycle to play the other animation, which is potentially easier but could cause cuts in animation between the run cycle and the other animation; OR you could wait until the current run cycle is completed before switching animations if you have a matching set of animations. Assuming you don't try this code:

```
walkcount = 0
walkanim = [list of images]
fightanim = [list of images]

if direction:
    win.blit(walkanim[walkCount // n], (x, y))
    if walkCount + 1 >= 18:
        walkCount = 0
    else:
        walkCount += 1
    if (whenever the fight animation is triggered):
        for i in range(len(fightanim)):
            win.blit(walkanim[i // n], (x, y))
```

I don't know that much about the structure of your game/code, so that may require some tweaking. Regardless, hope it helps! -Theo